# (Fortigate) Proxy blocking flash access to an XML file

Tags: xml, flash, proxy

I have a site, with an Iframe, with a flash file inside the IFrame that accesses an XML file thats on the same server. On every single computer, the flash file loads the XML file perfectly. However on one computer running Windows Vista and IE7 which has Fortigate Proxy (the title of IE7 is now *Microsoft Internet Explorer provided by Fortigate Proxy*), the flash file does not load the XML.

Has fortigate or any proxy been known to block access to XML files in Flash files inside an IFrame or similar? Also noted is that PLUpload doesnt work on the same machine (www.plupload.com).

I don't have much knowledge of proxys, any help would be grand.